# $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ - linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a lot of posts about that subject, but I'm not sure.

Task: 
Check if 
$$f(x)=\sin(x)  $$
and 
$$g(x)=\cos(x)  $$

are linearly independent in the space of functions.

That's what I have done:

$a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) = 0$, 
so $a=0$ and $b=0$.

for $x=0  $, 
$a \sin(0) + b \cos(0) = 0$, then 
$a\cdot  0 + b\cdot 1 = 0$.

for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$a \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) + b \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$, then 
$b \cdot 1 + a \cdot  0 = 0$

what am I supposed to write then? :)

Comment: Your second equation (for $x=\pi/2$) has an incorrect conclusion. This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have the right ideas but you need to write your solution more clearly. We are trying to show that if for all $x$
$$
a\sin(x) + b\cos(x) = 0\tag{1}
$$
then $a=0$ and $b=0$. In particular (1) holds for $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$. Substituting these into (1) we get
$$
\begin{align}
a(0)+b(1)&=0\\
a(1)+b(0)&=0.
\end{align}
$$
The first equation says that $b=0$ and the second  that $a=0$.

Comment: that;s enough for that task :) ?

Comment: Yes we've shown that the definition of linear independence is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is not zero:

$$W(\sin, \cos)(x) = \begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \\ \cos x & -\sin x\end{vmatrix} = -\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x = -1 \ne 0$$

Therefore $\{\sin, \cos\}$ is linearly independent.